# In Messenger bot webview , How to know that user has completed registration form

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

In messenger bot i was showing a webview form here how can we know that user completed form and trigger a message a particular user about successfully form submitted

Answer (score 0):

When the submit button for the form is clicked you can call `requestCloseBrowser()` to close the webview, and send an event to your webhook to notify it to send the follow up message in the conversation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview#close